# One-to-many or many-to-many?

Tags: sql, database-design

This is BestPractice question (or at least I hope it is).

EDIT: This example is just to clarify the problem. It could be Person, Office, ContactInformation.

The problem:

There are 3 tables:

```
RightsSet
(
    ID,
    CanView,
    CanEdit,
    ObjectTypeID,
    ObjectID
)

User
(
    ID,
    Username,
    Password,
    ProfileID
)

ProfileID
(
    ID,
    Name,
    Description
)
```

Both User and Profile can have multiple RightsSets.
RightsSet must belong to 1 (and only 1) User or Profile.

How to achieve this?
Should I create additional tables

```
UserRightsSets
(
    UserID,
    RightsSetID
)

ProfileRightsSets
(
    ProfileID,
    RightsSetID
)
```

The problem with this is:
How to make sure when ProfileRightsSet is deleted, the RightsSet is also deleted (because that RightsSet belongs to profile and to profile alone)?
How to make sure RightsSet belongs only to profile and not to Profile and User?

Alternatively, I could modify RightsSet table

```
RightsSet
(
    ID,
    CanView,
    CanEdit,
    ObjectTypeID,
    ObjectID,
    UserID,
    ProfileID
)
```

The problem with this... Well, what if multiple objects share RightsSet? (Ok, I can't think of any example, but I'm sure there are valid scenarios where more than 2 kinds of entity share one kind of entity.)

Comment: The whole thing seems rather poorly thought out - why not do what most permission systems do and use roles which can be assigned to any number of users?

Comment: Well... It's realy not question about users and profiles... It's about relationship between 3 entities in which 2 entity can have multiple of 3rd, but 3rd must belong to precisely 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a tough one for me to wrap my head around but you might consider the structure below:

```
Entity
---------
EntityId
ProfileId --nullable
UserId --nullable

RightsSet
----------
EntityId
CanView
CanEdit
ObjectTypeID
ObjectID
```

With this method you can specify a `UNIQUE` constraint on `ProfileId` and `UserId` in the `Entity` table and then create as many records in `RightsSet` as is needed.  Two possible problems would be when `ProfileId` and `UserId` in `Entity` are both null or when they both have values.  You could probably do some validation before you insert records to ensure this does not happen.

Comment: If I added Unique on ProfileId and UserId, would'n that eliminate possibillity of user having multiple RightsSets?

Comment: @Andrija: No, you could have many RightsSets that have same `EntityId` so belong to same profile or user.

Comment: Of course. PK for RightsSet is moved to entity. That, actually, makes a lot of sense. Than you!

Answer (score 2):

Add a supertype `Entity` table that has subtypes `User` and `Profile` (`1:1` relationship with both).

Then, let the `Entity` and `RightsSet` be in `1:n` relationship.

Comment: I accepted the other answer because it's clearee. Even if they are, essentially, the same. Anyhow, thank you!

Comment: Thanks. Notice that they are not identical answers, only similar. There will be no NULLs in mine. And the JOINs will be different in the 2 versions, not sure which will be clearer.